# HTML Redirection to Current Server

Tags: html

I have a web site hosted on two separate servers backed by a single database. When I add links to said website, I use the FQDN in the `<a href>` portion. I would like to set the HTML to keep the user on whatever server they happen to be browsing from. Is there a way to do this? I can't use JavaScript or anything else besides standard HTML on this portion of the website.

Example: A link is set up to go to https://somewebsite.com, but when the user browses the website from https://someotherwebsite.com, the page redirects them to the first server (somewebsite.com).

Comment: You might be able to use a `<base href="http://somewebsite.com/">` tag for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I add links to said website, I use the FQDN in the  portion.

Simply, don't do that.

Suppose I'm on the page at the URL `https://example.com`, and I want to go to the page at `https://example.com/something-else`.  Your link should look like this:

```
<a href="something-else">
```

This works because `something-else` is in the same path.  If you wanted to ensure you go to the top level of the tree, you could also use:

```
<a href="/something-else">
```